# How to style forms produced by django_comments_framework using tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, django-comments

I was trying to use tailwindcss plugins **[tailwindcss-forms](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms)** to style comment `forms` produced by **[django comments framework](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments)**.

**tailwindcs-forms** requires tailwind styling `class` to be applied on `<input type="">` level.

However, in **django comments framework**, the HTML template file (**[form.html](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/templates/comments/form.html)** for example) has no access to `<input type="">`, which is automatically produced during template rendering process via template `variables` such as `{{ form.comment }}`.

What should I do with this dilemma? whether styling `forms` produced by **django comments framework** using **tailwindcss-forms** is really possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can render the fields individually. For the comment field it can be given as following :

```
<textarea name="{{ form.comment.id_for_label }}" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="3000" id="{{ form.comment.html_name }} required"></textarea>
```

The class attribute can then be added to the field to perform tailwind styling. Similarly the remaining fields needs to be considered.

It should be noted that there are anti-spam attributes present in the form which should be considered while using custom template : https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?#notes-on-the-comment-form

Also refer : https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?#rendering-a-custom-comment-form